# Increase all characters by 1 (JAVA)

Tags: java, arrays, encryption

So I need help with increasing all characters in a file. Whole file is able to read and get all the info form the user but when it comes to actual increasing all characters from (this case) a file it just outputs a blank file.

Goal of this program is to read in a users file get all the text from the file and increase or decrease the letters by one. So A is now a B or B is now a C or via versa B is now a A or C is now a B. When it goes to export/close the file it just is blank.

Here is that portion of the code:
            while (fileIn.hasNext())
            {
               letter.add(fileIn.next());

```
           for (int i = letter.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
           {
              ch = letter.get(i).charAt(0);

              ch--;

              fileout1.println(ch);
           }

           //Makes a new line at end of line
           System.out.println();
        }
```

Whole code is as follows:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Assignment9
{

   public static void main (String[] args)
   {
      Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
      Scanner fileIn;
      File f; 
      char ch = 65;
      String fileName = "";
      boolean userA = false;
      String usersChoice = "";
      ArrayList<String> letter = new ArrayList<String>();


      try
      {
         System.out.println("Please enter the file name that you would like encrypted/decrypted: ");
         fileName = in.nextLine();

         //Builds the file and attaches the Scanner
         f = new File (fileName);
         fileIn = new Scanner (f);
         PrintWriter fileout1 = new PrintWriter ("decrypt.txt");
         PrintWriter fileout2 = new PrintWriter ("encrypt.txt");


         System.out.println("Would you like to Decrypt or Encrypt the file?");  
         usersChoice = in.nextLine();
         userA = true;


         //Loop through the file and translate the characters
         if (usersChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("Decrypt"))
         {
            while (fileIn.hasNext())
            {
               letter.add(fileIn.next());

               for (int i = letter.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
               {
                  ch = letter.get(i).charAt(0);

                  ch--;

                  fileout1.println(ch);
               }

               //Makes a new line at end of line
               System.out.println();
            }

            //Decrease every letter by 1 (runs backwords)


            System.out.println("Decrypt.txt has been created.");
            fileout1.close();

         }

         //encrypts the file by increasing by 1
         if (usersChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("encrypt"))
         {
            while (fileIn.hasNext())
            {
               letter.add(fileIn.next());
            }

            //Decrease every letter by 1 (runs backwords)
            for (int i = letter.size() -1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                System.out.println(letter);

               ch --;
            }

            System.out.println("Encrypted.txt has been created.");
            fileout2.close();;
         }             
      } //end of try     

      catch (FileNotFoundException e)
      {
         System.out.println("Sorry invalid file, please try again");
         fileName = in.nextLine();
      }


   } // end of main

} //end of program
```

Comment: And **where** do you *write* to `fileout1`?

Comment: What happens when the character is 'A' and you decrease the character by 1?

Comment: So A should become a Z. And I guess thats where I am wrong? should this line:

  ch = letter.get(i).charAt(0);

                ch --; //decreases the character by one                                               shoudln't this line be writing to the file?

Comment: turn a char into int as ascii code and turn it back after you decrease it.

Comment: That (i.e. A should become Z) may be one area where you're wrong, but you have at least two more serious problems than that.

Comment: @wijaya a `char` is already an ASCII code (if it's in the range 0-127).  A `char` is actually an integer type.  Converting to an `int` and back accomplishes nothing.

Comment: Would anyone be willing to work with me one on one? I'm pretty confused.

Comment: Start by answering Elliott's question.

Comment: Well it would have to be in the fileHas next because it doesn't have anything to read in you can't translate it. So if we do it in the for loop we should be able to increase every character by one if we can get the char of each character then increase it.

Comment: OK, then try adding it.  See if it makes things work, or if it at least gets you closer.

Comment: Ok good news :) Got it to decrease the letter. So I'm running into the problem someone mentioned before if it's a A it just outputs nothing. then it only does the first letter and nothing else.

Comment: So does my code not check to see if there is a next character in the file as it sits then? Because I thought the while condition should loop as long as it's true but it obviously isn't working.

Comment: @ajb I updated my code to write to the output file, any ideas why it only grabs the first character and not the whole file of characters?

Comment: Post a runnable [mcve]. What you have posted now doesn't compile, we don't know what fileIn is, what fileOut is, etc.

Comment: I added the whole program now.

Comment: @TylerK `charAt(0)` gets the first character.  You don't use `charAt` with any other index.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like as below,

```
    FileReader fr = null;
    FileWriter fw = null;
    int c;
    try {
        fr = new FileReader("C:\\Zia\\test.txt");
        fw = new FileWriter("C:\\Zia\\Result.txt");
        while ((c = fr.read()) != -1) {
            if(c!=32)
            fw.write((char)--c);
            else
                fw.write((char)c);
        }
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        close(fr);
        close(fw);
    }
```

My `test.txt` file contains the below content,

```
Hello How are you doing.
```

and result.txt contains the below result after decreasing the char by one.

```
Gdkkn Gnv `qd xnt cnhmf-
```

you may interchange the file name for both the file for Reader and writer and increase the char by 1 to verify the decryption.

Comment: So your code compared to mine, mine works but only picks up the first character of the file instead of the whole text in the file should the while (hasNext()) pick up if ther is more text and execute the code in the loop? But it doesnt.